# Python wsgi application gives internal server error after hosting on apache virtual host

Tags: python-2.7, apache, mod-wsgi, odoo-11

I am trying to deploy odoo 11 on apache2.4 with python 2.7 in Windows.After hours of googling i completed configuring apache virtual host and wsgi config fine pretty fine. but it still shows internal server error.
My apache configuration is like this.

```
WSGIPythonPath D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py       
    ErrorLog D:/Workspace/Odoo/logs/odoo-error.log
    CustomLog D:/Workspace/Odoo/logs/odoo-access.log combined       
    DocumentRoot "D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/"
    <Directory "D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/">
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
        Require all granted     
        Order Allow,Deny 
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/">
        <Files "odoo-wsgi.py">
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
            Allow from all          
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After checking the error log i found this

```
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.838364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] End of script output before headers: odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.839362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.839362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py", line 3, in <module>\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.839362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     import odoo\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.839362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.839362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     from . import modules\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.840362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\modules\\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.840362 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.841363 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\modules\\graph.py", line 10, in <module>\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.841363 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     import odoo.tools as tools\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.841363 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\tools\\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.841363 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     from .config import config\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.842364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\tools\\config.py", line 648, in <module>\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.842364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     config = configmanager()\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.842364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\tools\\config.py", line 121, in __init__\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.842364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     group.add_option("-D", "--data-dir", dest="data_dir", my_default=_get_default_datadir(),\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.843364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\tools\\config.py", line 49, in _get_default_datadir\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.843364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     return func(appname=release.product_name, appauthor=release.author)\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.844364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\tools\\appdirs.py", line 110, in site_data_dir\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.844364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     path = os.path.normpath(_get_win_folder("CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA"))\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.844364 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:   File "D:\\Workspace\\Odoo\\odoo\\odoo\\tools\\appdirs.py", line 390, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.845365 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215:     dir = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, getattr(shellcon, csidl_name), 0, 0)\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
[Fri Jun 01 22:58:57.845365 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 9240:tid 1188] [client 127.0.0.1:13282] AH01215: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024893, 'The system cannot find the path specified.', None, None)\r: D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
```

Comment: If you are trying to use mod_wsgi, you should get rid of the ``AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py`` lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.i added `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py` in `httpd.conf` file too. should i remove that lines too.

Comment: I removed the lines now it gives me this error : `mod_wsgi (pid=10616): Target WSGI script 'D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.,mod_wsgi (pid=10616): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo/odoo-wsgi.py, ImportError: No module named odoo'`. please help.

Comment: Possibly instead of ``WSGIPythonPath D:/Workspace/Odoo/odoo`` you want ``WSGIPythonPath D:/Workspace/Odoo``. Can only guess as you don't describe your code layout.